# How to adjust constant/drift to ARIMA forecasting model and how to scale down the cycle up/down size?

Tags: r, arima, seasonality

I ran ARIMA model on a dataset to forecast the next 180 days sales after training period. My data is daily sales data and is provided here [sales data](https://github.com/Timeght/time-series).  It has 1267 periods. For the period 729~808, there are errors in the original data so I replaced them from forecasted values based on period 1~728. The data is stationary after one order of differencing.  The periodgraph suggests that the data appears to have 3.5 and 7 days seasonality.  With fourier regressors added to auto.arima function, I am able to include seasonality to fit the cycle of sales change. However, the forecasted data appear to match the test data poorly due to two problems:

1. the model forecasting results on average seem to be lower than the real test data, which suggests that a constant can be added to the model to improve the accuracy. I have set allowdrift=TRUE, allowmean = TRUE in the auto.arima() function.  But the results show it is not ideal. How do I adjust the value of constant that auto.arima add to the model in R? Is there other ways to add constant beyond allowdrift and allowmean ?
2. the model forecasted the right up and down cycle, which suggests the seasonalities are added correctly. But the cycle has a much larger range than the test data. I think scaling down the cycle might help to improve forecasting accuracy but I am not clear how to adjust the range of forecasting cycle?

Below are my codes and output:

#create time series

p <- periodogram(diff(temp)) #examine seasonality periods

y0<-temp$Volume %>% msts(seasonal.periods = c(3.5,7)) # two seasonals

train <- head(y0, length(y0) - 30*6)

test <- tail(y0,  30*6)

#ARIMA model testing

fit<-auto.arima(train,seasonal=F, xreg=fourier(train, K=c(1.75,3.5)), allowdrift=TRUE, allowmean = TRUE)

fit_f <- forecast(fit,
xreg= fourier(train, K=c(1.75,3.5),h=180),
h= 180)

autoplot(fit_f)+autolayer(test)

#check accuracy measures

fit_f_v<-as.data.frame(fit_f)

MdAPE_ARIMA<-errorMetric(as.data.frame(fit_f_v$'Point Forecast'), as.data.frame(test), type="APE", statistic = "Md")

MdAPE_ARIMA

accuracy(fit_f, test)

[image: ARIMA forecast results]

If anyone can help to address my questions, it would be greatly appreciated!